# Regarding the form for renunciation of Indian citizenship

Tags: india, us-citizens

I am applying to CKGS for renouncing my Indian citizenship after I have acquired US citizenship. While filling the form a question asks: **spouse's name as in CURRENT US passport**. But the US passport doesn't have names of any relatives. So what should be put there as name of spouse? Should I still put the name of my spouse or should I say NA? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have no personal experience with this issue. Because US passports don't display the name of the passport holder's spouse, the correct response would seem to be "NA."

Comment: The form might be meaning the name of your spouse, in _his/her_ passport, not yours

Comment: @CSM Certainly could be so, the form's question is ambiguous.

Comment: @Anurag A Please post a scan or screenshot of the actual question, so we can see its wording.